# Can't use methods on divs - TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple problem yet can't find a solution.

So I have a div and I want to delete it with jquery and hide it using css and "display".

When I try to delete it calling "delete()" like this:

```
$("#sendReplyBox").delete();
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'delete'
```

Ok, this happens because I have an object. It's ok, I just have to do the following:

```
$("#sendReplyBox")[0].delete();
```

Well, doing that gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'delete'
```

Why does this happens with "delete" method, "css" method,etc? I searched for the answer, yet I did not find it.

Comment: I've never seen the `delete()` method...

Comment: There is no method `delete()` that works on DOM elements, neither in jQuery nor in javascript, so what are you really trying to do ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Ok, so using detach works... http://api.jquery.com/detach/ I wonder why remove don't?

Comment: Could it be that you're using delete() in all your examples ?

Comment: .remove() works, you are doing something wrong for sure...

Comment: I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... I tried on the chrome console and it didn't work using delete().

Comment: @Th3lmuu90: Why do you expect `delete()` to work? It's neither a native JavaScript method nor jQuery method.

Comment: Yes it is:  
api.jquery.com/remove

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 that's the REMOVE method, you are using DELETE in you question.

Comment: Jeezez man, you've linked to the documentation for `remove()` yourself, several comments and an answer is telling you it's called `remove()` not `delete()`, and you're still not sure why `delete()` doesn't work. Maybe you should consider a [Darwin Award](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Awards)

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#sendReplyBox").remove();`

Check it from w3c http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp

Or maybe you can hide/show as shown here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: I always check more than multiple sources don't worry, but thanks for informing ^^